# Get Text from iframe

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I have the following HTML

```
<iframe id ="myIframe">
     #document
         <head>...</head>
        <body>Text I want to get is here</body>
</iframe>
```

I only know the iframe's id. Using JavaScript, how can I extract the text from the body?

Comment: is your iframe src from same domain or different?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming your iframe is in the same domain as your HTML:

```
var myIFrame = document.getElementById("myIframe");
var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

Otherwise you'll face some [Same Origin Policy](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy) issues.