# Copying text from IFRAME into the INPUT field on the parent page

Tags: javascript, iframe

When the visitor clicks the button after typing a text in the INPUT field which is in a framed page , is it  possible to copy the typed  text into  the INPUT field which is on the parent page ?

iframed page code : page1.html

```
<form action="">
   Search:<input type="text" name="searchname"><input type="submit" value="send" size="45">
</form>
```

Parent page:

```
<IFRAME id="iframe1" src="page1.html"></IFRAME><BR>

   You searched:<INPUT type="text" id="result">
```

I want that the searched items display on the parent page.
Thanks.

Comment: Are both pages hosted on the same server?

Answer (score 1):

In parent
Create function which receive text...

```
function UpdateSearchNameToResult(msg){
   document.getElementById('result').value = msg;
}
```

---

In iframe
Create function which send search name
for submit button on "page1.html"

and call  `parent.UpdateSearchNameToResult(yourval);`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13038806/492258)

jquery version, you can try :

```
$("#result").val($("#iframe1 form input[name=searchname]").val())
```