# HTML/JavaScript: How to copy text from a iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm kinda new to web development.  I'm trying to copy text from a `iframe` into a `textarea` on a `Bootstrap-html` webpage.

An example of my code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/fe5ahoyw/

**JavaScript**
I have tried:

```
var a = document.getElementById('LD1');
var b = document.getElementById('OD1');
if (a != null)
{
    b.value = a.value;
}
```

I have also tried:

```
var a = document.getElementById('LD1').innerHTML;
var a = document.getElementById('LD1').value;
var a = document.getElementById('LD1').html;
```

Any help would be any help would be much appreciated

*Frostie*

Comment: You don't have any content in the iframe right now

Comment: I have it linked to text file on my C drive.
I tried link it to a text file on line, but doesn't come across on jsfiddle!

Comment: that would not work , due to browser same origin policy, I believe. You may want to use a server , but tht is later

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510784/copying-text-from-iframe-into-the-input-field-on-the-parent-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSFiddle is currently trying to access a http resource. As JSFiddle itself is http*s*, most browsers will not like this very much.

That said, the selectors you are using inside the code are ... off. You need to get `the frame itself` -> `content of the frame` -> `element within the frame you are interested in`. I'd suggest using something like:

```
var a = document.getElementById('OD1');
var iFrame =  document.getElementById('LD1');
var iFrameDocument = iFrame.contentDocument || iFrame.contentWindow.document;
content = iFrameDocument.body.textContent;
alert(content);

if (content)
{
  a.value = content.value;
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
I tried your soluation and got the following error:

'Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.'

Comment: This now works for IE, can this be changed to work in Chrome??